# Type strong utility to convert array of KV pairs to original dictionary

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a function `dictToKv` which converts a dictionary into an array of object's with both `key` and `value` properties:

```
/** used to help get type literals versus wide types */
type Narrowable = string | number | boolean | symbol | object | undefined | void | null | {};

/** just like Object.keys() but preserves keyof relationship */
function keys<T extends {}>(obj: T) { Object.keys(obj) as unknown as Array<keyof T> };

/** Helps shape an object into an array where key and value relationship is retained */
type KeyValueFrom<T extends object> = Array<{ [K in keyof T]: { key: K; value: T[K] } }[keyof T]>;

/** convert a dictionary to an array of objects with key and value props */
function dictToKv<N extends Narrowable, T extends Record<string, N>>(obj: T): KeyValueFrom<T> {
  return keys(obj).map(k => {
    return { key: k, value: obj[k] };
  });
}
```

With the help of my `KeyValueFrom<T>` utility I can explicitly state the type of the return and this return value is not iterable but retains all type literal info:

```
const obj = { id: 123, foo: "bar" } as const;
const kv1 = dictToKv(obj);

for(const kv of kv1) {
  if(kv.key === "id") {
    // strong types with no unions
    type cases = [
      Expect<Equal<typeof kv.key, "id">>,
      Expect<Equal<typeof kv.value, 123>>
    ]
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having is going in reverse. The run-time aspects of the inverse are simple but the hard part seems to be creating a type utility to do this inverted conversion.

What I've got so far is:

```
type DictFrom<T extends { key: string; value: unknown }[]> = 
   Record<T[number]["key"], T[number]["value"]>;
```

This does type the keys of the dictionary properly and maintains literal types but the values are now union types:

```
type Inverse = DictFrom<typeof kv1>;
type cases = [
  // Expect<Equal<Inverse, typeof obj>>
  Expect<Equal<Inverse, { foo: 123 | "bar"; id: 123 | "bar" }>>
];
```

Is there any way to achieve non-union types using Typescript's inference?

> [Typescript Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mMRMQW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done fairly straightforwardly with [key remapping in mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as), like this:

```
type DictFrom<T extends { key: string; value: unknown }[]> = 
  { [R in T[number] as R["key"]]: R["value"] };
```

Using your `KeyValueFrom` to do this:

```
interface Foo {
  id: number,
  foo: string
}

type FooKV = KeyValueFrom<Foo>;
/* type FooKV = ({
    key: "id";
    value: number;
} | {
    key: "foo";
    value: string;
})[] */
```

we can more-or-less undo it with `DictFrom`:

```
type FooDict = DictFrom<FooKV>
/* type FooDict = {
    id: number;
    foo: string;
} */
```

Whether or not these are seen to be exactly equal in your test has to do with things like `readonly` or optionality and other quirks that might cause `DictFrom<KeyValueFrom<T>>` to differ from `T`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBA0lMA1AhgGwK5QGICcD2AtgDwAqMUAHiFAHYAmAzjPgEYBWUAxiAHwwBeGAEFcuFGGIBvGAG04MAJa0YAa0T4AZjFIBdAFwwZ6sIbgBuGADd0WQ6Xm6YAXxeyTWnbt7ngwZTS4mihcsNj4+EbAMEr0hrQYhKxQuAA00TCaEYaMILjKAObAzqCQYRFwSILwiKiYOAQk4fg+wAD0AFQw4NAwzZXVABRSGTEmhgBEivQTvjExNvXxicm4vq4APlHzaoiTWfizo9a2UDl5hesAlLJOHW1+PbAAIoo8eERkFNR0TEa7phguXytAKlkWdhgGFoqlo+AA7ipnLd+EIZLIAEpKFQOBJJFK6FDMDGyCYmCa6AwwEkTCFQCkuXylXrNV48apskAfJoVJC8dpdJ59CKc6ojHbTZb4tbHA7nEFg4owe5AA)

Comment: Fantastic ... typing arrays does my head in but your solution works perfectly for my use case.